# Zip several soundfile-formats without deflate

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a folder that i want to zip but not deflate the soundfiles (since i'll create an expansion file for android).

TO achieve that one can use the -n flag. that is

```
zip -n .mp3 main_expansion thaisounds
```

then a new zip-folder is created where the mp3-soundfiles are stored but not deflated.

The problem is that I also have two other sounfile-format there

```
.wav
.3ga
```

If I add those as follows

```
 zip -n .mp3,.wav,.3ga main_expansion thaisounds
```

Then the program starts to deflate all files though I use the -n flag.

So - my question - How should I use the zip-command to not deflating the mediafiles when there are several formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my version of the zip man-page, you need to use colons to separate the suffixes:

```
   -n suffixes
   --suffixes suffixes
          Do not attempt to compress files named with the given suffixes.  Such files are simply stored (0% compres-
          sion) in the output zip file, so that zip doesn’t waste its time trying to compress  them.   The  suffixes
          are separated by either colons or semicolons.  For example:

                 zip -rn .Z:.zip:.tiff:.gif:.snd  foo foo
```

So you'd end up with:

```
zip -n .mp3:.wav:.3ga main_expansion thaisounds
```

Comment: Thanks at devoloper.android http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html further down they give an example of this but uses semicolon - which wont work at all. :-)

Comment: for want of a `shift`, the command was lost...

Comment: Any ideas of how to zip all content (without deflating) so I don't have to list all the suffixes (extensions i.e .mp3:.Wav .....)? The problem now is that one of the wav-files for some reason doesnt have an extension so its deflated. thanks in advance

Comment: `zip -0` indicates "no compression"; maybe that'll do it?

Comment: thanks - that solved the problem - I am relatively new to linux so I have to be better studying man-pages :-)